# Remove the bottom line present in android tab bar

Tags: android-widget

How do I remove the line which is present at the bottom of the deselected tabs.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the underline from the unselected tab, use `tabWidget.setStripeEnabled("false");`.

If you want to use it dynamically in coding and if you want to write in xml, then set tabwidget property: `android:tabStripeEnabled=false`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom tab, this tutorial is very good http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136, it would give the full flexibility over the tabs and for the tutorial case, run without mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider); it won't show the bottom line.

For non customized one, maybe mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null) it will work

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay, in your example the white gray line is present for deselected tabs , i need to remove the lines which is present at the bottom of the deselected tabs . please help me

Comment: for the tutorial case, run without mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider); it won't show the bottom line. And for non customized one, maybe mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null) it will work